# Enterprise Territory Management (Territory Management 2.0) and Customizable Forecasting? Possible?

Tags: territory-management, forecast

I want to implement Territory Management and Forecasts but the new orgs offer Enterprise Territory Management and Collaborative Forecasts, which are not integrated to work. Can I shift to Customizable forecasts along with Enterprise Territory Management (Territory Management 2.0) ?

I want to use the features of Enterprise Territory Management (Territory Management 2.0) but I also need forecasting based on territories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, customizable forecasting is only available with standard TM, but not with Enterprise TM.